# Asymptotic of sum with binomial coefficients.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, binomial-coefficients

Let $\displaystyle f(n,k) = \sum_{m \le k} \binom{n}{m}$. We need to show $\displaystyle f(n,k) \sim \frac{2^{nH(k/n)}}{\sqrt{2\pi k(n-k)/n}}(1 + o(1))$, where $k = o(n)$  and $k \to \infty$

Actually I've thought about three ideas :

1) Consider $\displaystyle \xi _{i}$ be Bernoulli random variables, and use CLT for estimating this sum.

2) Use Stirling approximation.

3) Use Abel summation.

The former idea give the worst asymptotic. The second one isn't usable , because $m$ is just a constant for finitely many times.

The last idea gives me :

(1) = $\displaystyle \sum_{m \le k} \binom{n}{m} = \sum \frac{n!}{m!} \cdot \frac{1}{(n-m)!}$, let $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n-x)}$ and $a_m = n! / m!$. Hence we have $\displaystyle A(x) = \sum_{m \le x} \frac{n!}{m!} \sim n! e$, so we would have something like (1) $\displaystyle \sim$ $\displaystyle \frac{en!}{\Gamma(n-k)} + \int_{1}^{k} \frac{en! \Gamma'(n-x)}{\Gamma^2(n-x)} dx$. Major part of integral gives us $\displaystyle \frac{en!}{\Gamma(n-k)}$, so we obtain $\displaystyle \frac{2e n!}{\Gamma(n-k)} = \frac{2en!}{(n-k)!}$ even Stirling approximation doesn't give us the mentioned result. Any hint?

Attempt (using CLT). Let $S_n = \sum X_i$, where $X_i$ i.r.v with Bernoulli distribution and $p = 1/2$. Hence we have $2^n \mathbb{P}( S_n \le k) = \sum ^{k} \binom{n}{m}$. So we should estimate this probability.

Using CLT we have : $ \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}(S_n) }{\sqrt{\mathbb{Var}(S_n)}} \le \frac{k - \mathbb{E}(S_n)}{ \sqrt{\mathbb{Var}(S_n)}}\right)$. Thus for $n \to \infty$ we have that probability estimates as $F_{Z} \left( \frac{k - n/2}{ \sqrt{n/4}}\right)$ which doesnt give us a given estimation. Maybe this approach can be obtained and upgraded?

Comment: Is the $t$ in $H(t/n)$ a typo?

Comment: @martycohen yes

Comment: What you want is called a large deviations result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is that a formal idea?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan and if I right to understand. It allows us estimate one binomial coefficient, not the sum of coefficients. Or I fault ?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can you give me a link for reading this?

Comment: Why do you "need to show"? Are you sure this is right?

Comment: @vonbrand looks like right result. Actually I figured out that $\binom{n}{k}$ has the same asymptotic, hence I should prove that $f(n,k) / \binom{n}{k}$ goes to $1$. It looks like so, because $\sum_{1 \le m \le k} \binom{n}{m} / \binom{n}{k}$ behaves like $\sum (k/n)^m$ , which goes to zero with big $n$.

Comment: @openspace, if that is right for the last term, it would mean the others are much smaller...

Comment: @vonbrand it means that sum of others is small. It deals with $k = o(n)$.